# How to dynamically generate pydantic input models for FastAPI endpoints?

Tags: python, fastapi, type-hinting, typing, pydantic

I am wondering if the following might be possible (and how to go about it):

I am working one a FastAPI application, where on the back-end there is a modular application.
An application consists of different pipeline, which are just workflow that need an input and an output. Each pipeline inherits from this baseclass:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, List, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel

pipeline_input_T = TypeVar("pipeline_input_T", bound=BaseModel)
pipeline_output_T = TypeVar("pipeline_output_T", bound=BaseModel)


class BasePipeline(Generic[pipeline_input_T, pipeline_output_T], ABC):


    @abstractmethod
    async def run(self, input_data: pipeline_input_T) -> pipeline_output_T:
        pass

    # other stuff...
```

This is the first time getting a bit deeper into type hints, so please feel free if my approach is incorrect. Anyway, the idea is now to have pipelines with different input types inherit from this class, for example:

```
class SomeItem(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: int


class SomePipeline(BasePipeline[SomeItem, bytes]):
    
    # other stuff

    async def run(self, input_data: SomeItem) -> bytes:

        # do something to calculate a result
        return result
```

Based on the application different pipelines are used, each with different input models. Pipelines are stored in a dictionary of type `Dict[str, BasePipeline]`

My question is, if it is possible to dynamically generate endpoints with the correct input model, something like the following:

```
for name, pipeline in application.pipelines.items():

    @app.post(
        f"/pipelines/{name}/run", tags=["Pipeline"], status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK
    )
    def run_pipeline(input_data: CorrectType??) -> Any:
        return pipeline.run(input_data)
```

The problem with this approach is that the type used in this case is the BasePipeline's `pipeline_input_T` which is just really is just a generic placeholder. I have also tried to add a `get_input_type` function to the pipelines which returns the correct input model type. This seems to work with FastAPI, however `mypy` testing statically will fail with

> error: Variable "xxxx" is not valid as a type

I'm wondering if there is a possible solution for this problem.

Comment: And how do you expect **static** type checks by `mypy` to pick up on annotations that resolve at runtime? _Static type checkers don't execute your code, they just read it._ You can of course dynamically set up the signature for your route handler function correctly, such that the FastAPI router can identify the relevant models, as you already figured out. But there is no way to let `mypy` understand that signature. A better approach is to leverage your generic class and define a generic route handler there as @Hernán-Alarcón suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that if your path operation function has the same arguments (except `self`), returns the same value and does exactly the same as the `run(...)` method, you can just pass the method to the `app.post(...)` decorator. Example:

```python
import abc
import inspect
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

import fastapi
import pydantic

pipeline_input_T = TypeVar("pipeline_input_T", bound=pydantic.BaseModel)
pipeline_output_T = TypeVar("pipeline_output_T", bound=pydantic.BaseModel)


class BasePipeline(Generic[pipeline_input_T, pipeline_output_T], abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    async def run(self, input_data: pipeline_input_T) -> pipeline_output_T:
        pass


class SomeItem(pydantic.BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: int


class SomeOutput(pydantic.BaseModel):
    c: bytes


class SomePipeline(BasePipeline[SomeItem, SomeOutput]):
    async def run(self, input_data: SomeItem) -> SomeOutput:
        return SomeOutput(c="Hello world".encode("utf-8"))


class AnotherItem(pydantic.BaseModel):
    d: float


class AnotherOutput(pydantic.BaseModel):
    e: bool


class AnotherPipeline(BasePipeline[AnotherItem, AnotherOutput]):
    async def run(self, input_data: AnotherItem) -> AnotherOutput:
        return AnotherOutput(e=True)


# Get the pipelines somehow
pipelines = [SomePipeline(), AnotherPipeline()]

app = fastapi.FastAPI()

# Iterate over the pipelines
for pipeline in pipelines:
    # Get the class name of the pipeline
    name = pipeline.__class__.__name__
    # Add a POST path operation
    app.post(
        f"/pipelines/{name}/run",
        summary=name,
        tags=["Pipeline"],
        status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_200_OK,
        # Pass the return annotation as response model
        response_model=inspect.signature(pipeline.run).return_annotation
    )(pipeline.run)  # Pass the method directly
```

Both pipelines in the docs:

[image: Swagger docs]

Request body and responses of one of the pipelines:

[image: Request body and responses]